# Not able to open the large File Size PDF in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, adobe, reader

I am not able to open the large size PDF file(more than 1 gb) in IE 11. I am getting this error to open the PDF file "File does not begin with -%pdf- in internet explorer 11".

I am having Adobe Reader XI and Windows 7 in my system.
Can anybody help me out to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The first line of a PDF file is a header identifying the version of the PDF specification to which the file conforms. For a file conforming to PDF 1.7, the header should be
%PDF−1. 7

It appears your document is missing this header. Confirm you have a valid PDF before attempting to open it. This error is not related to file size.

Comment: But it is opening in Chrome browser it means it is valid PDF

Comment: The spec says that a PDF must begin with a %PDF-1.x comment, but it is possible to find PDFs that have a prefix of data before this header. To accommodate those, Acrobat and perhaps Chrome's PDF parser will allow the file if the header is within the first 1kb of the beginning of the file.  It may be that IE11 is not so accommodating.